# Toptabs are not showing up when using react-native-navigation [V2]

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

When trying to create toptab navigation in react-native-navigation v2 from wix I am unable to get the top tabs to appear. Below is the code I am trying to use. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
stack: {
        children: [
          {
            topTabs: {
              children: [
                {
                  component: {
                    name: 'Screen1',
                    options: {
                      topTab: {
                        title: 'Tab 1',
                      },
                    },
                  },
                },
                {
                  component: {
                    name: 'Screen2',
                    options: {
                      topTab: {
                        title: 'Tab 2',
                      },
                    },
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone passing by here, this is a bug that is currently being worked on by the wix react-native-navigation team. See https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/4485